# Why am I getting NullReferenceException when I try to write out the tag of the gameobject what was hit by a raycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I don't know why I'm getting it. It only pops up when the raycast hits the object.

```
void Update(){
RaycastHit2D hitSideRight = new RaycastHit2D();
            hitSideRight = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, Vector2.right, 1.2f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));
            Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, Vector2.right* 1.2f);

            RaycastHit2D hitSideLeft = new RaycastHit2D();
            hitSideLeft = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, -Vector2.right, 1.2f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));
            Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -Vector2.right* 1.2f);

            if(hitSideLeft.collider != null || hitSideRight.collider != null){
                CancelMove();
                Debug.Log(hitSideRight.collider.tag.ToString());
            }
}
```

I get the error for this line of code (only when the ray contacts with the object) : `Debug.Log(hitSideRight.collider.tag.ToString());`

Comment: You get a NRE when it actually collided with the left side (making your condition true) and not the right side? And there is no need to `new` your two RaycastHit2Ds there.

Comment: but if I don't use new than it's just a simple pointer, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `||` for `&&` because if `hitSideLeft` is **not** null and `hitSideRight` is null, the condition will be **true** and you get a NullPointer

```
if(hitSideLeft.collider != null || hitSideRight.collider != null){
     CancelMove();
     Debug.Log(hitSideRight.collider.tag.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Oh...I didn't notice I wrote `hitSideRight` not `Left`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead if you want to keep the `||`

```
RaycastHit2D col = hitSideLeft.collider ?? hitSideRight.collider;
if(col != null){
     CancelMove();
     Debug.Log(col.tag.ToString());
}
```

But you should know... `Physics2D.Raycast(...)` Returns a `bool` not a `RaycastHit2D`

your raycasts should look like so:

```
RaycastHit2D hitSideRight;
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector2.right);
if(Physics2D.Raycast (ray, out hitSideRight, 1.2f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground")))
{}
```